# QGIS 3.12 - How to divide Polygon even areas

Tags: qgis, splitting

I'm trying to divide a 5ha paddock into .5ha "cells".

In QGIS terms I'm looking to subdivide an irregular polygon into sub-polygons which will have the same area inside and as near as possible straight dividing fences. Ideally this would be two steps:

1. Divide 5ha paddock into 2 2.5ha thin paddocks with a vertical line (red line below)
2. Divide each 2.5ha paddock into five 0.5ha paddocks with horizontal lines (blue lines, should be straight.

Ideal after result:
[image: Ideal after result with new polygon borders in MS paint]
I have seen the plugins Polygon splitter, divide polygon, and Split feature on steriods, but I cannot get any of them to work. At the end of this exercise I want a GPS route for the new fencelines